# Ошибка при тестировании приложения на реальном устройстве

Tags: android, rest

Приложение нормально работает на разных эмуляторах и устройствах других версий. На Samsung s4, версии 5.0.1 при обращении на сервер News API вылетает ошибка: `06-12 20:15:09.736 28876-28876/com.georgcantor.vipnews E/MainActivity: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

Как можно исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Посмотрите вот тут: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047414/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-java-security-cert-certpathvalidatorexcepti).